Optimal strategy for uniform distribution probability game
There are 2 players, Adam and Eve, playing a game. The rules are as follows: $n$ and $d$ are chosen randomly. Adam samples a value $v$, distributed uniformly on $[0,n]$, and can either cash out $v$ or pay Eve $d$ to re-sample. At what value of $v$ should Adam cash out at?
My thinking was that $E[v]$ will always be $n/2$, and we should look at $d/E[v]$, to see how many re-samples we can afford and still have a positive ev, but I feel like that misses a lot of nuance in the variance/sd and what not. How can we solve this?
If, in addition, Adam has to pay Eve $x$ to play the game. What is his optimal strategy then?

So $n$ and $d$ are fixed right? And you have to assume $n>d$ to make sense since if $d \geq n $ then he always stops at any value of $v$ immediately after his 1st try

Yes d <= n, and n and d do not change over the course of a game.

Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Mathematics Stack Exchange, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the CC BY-SA 4.0 licence, regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts can result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being locked and your account being temporarily suspended.

Rolled back this post

Let $X$ be a random variable representing Adam's final profit and $x = \mathbb{E}[X]$ denote the expected profit from playing this game.
Assume, at a given sampling, Adam has $v$ dollars. If he re-samples, then by starting the game over, he expects to make $x$ dollars again. However, he has to pay $d$ to do this resampling, so his expected earnings is $x-d$.
Meanwhile, if he keeps his current sampling, he leaves with $v$ dollars.
Thus, it only makes sense for him to resample when $x-d > v$.
Now, we use this to calculate $x$.
By the laws of expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[X | sample = v]].$$ So,
$$x = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[X | sample = v]].$$
First, we deal with $\mathbb{E}[X | sample = v]$.
As discussed above, given a sampling of $v$ dollars, Adam expects to make $x-d$ dollars if $v < x-d$ and $v$ dollars otherwise.
Since $v$ is sampled uniformly on $[0,N]$, the chance of picking a $v < x-d$ is given by $\frac{x-d}{N}.$
Thus, calculating expectation yields $$ \mathbb{E}[X | sample = v] = \frac{x-d}{N} \cdot (x-d) + \left(1 - \frac{x-d}{N} \right) \cdot v.$$
Now, we need to take the expectation of this quantity.
The only probabilistic part of the above is $v$, which is uniform on $[x-d, n].$ Thus, the expected value of the above is just the expected value of $v$ when chosen uniformly from $[x-d, n]$, namely $\frac{n + x-d}{2}.$
Thus, we obtain $$x = \frac{x-d}{N} \cdot (x-d) + \left(1 - \frac{x-d}{N} \right) \cdot \frac{n + x-d}{2}.$$
Expanding and simplifying this (skipping algebraic steps for readability) gives
$$\left(x - (d+n) \right)^2 = 2nd.$$
So, $$x = d+n - \sqrt{2nd}.$$
Hence, the optimal strategy is to only re-sample when your current number is less than $$n - \sqrt{2nd}.$$
This matches the other answer and also yields $30$ when $N=50, d=4$.

For some context, after I had failed the question I was told that the answer for n = 50 and d = 4 was 30. I think the solution is a a bit simpler, and intuitively I thought it was just v > EV + d, but I guess that did not hold. Im wondering if the ratio of d to variance means anything?

I believe this answer is wrong (and hard to understand too). The problem can be formulated as an optimal stopping problem, check my answer below. @jimsimons My answer below contains your example for $N=50$, $d=4$ as well.

Realized that there were some errors in my work. Fixed them and added more explanation for simplicity. Hopefully, it's more readable now. The beautiful part about this solution is it requires no advanced knowledge and relies only on simple expectation techniques.

The problem can be formulated as follows: Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a sequence of iid random variables, each is uniformly distributed on $[0,N]$. Adam is the guy who tries to maximize the expected payoff
$$ v(x) :=  \sup_{\tau: P(\tau < \infty) = 1} E[X_\tau - d\tau|X_0 =x], \quad x \in [0,N] $$
where the supremum runs over all finite stopping times $\tau$ of the natural filtration generated by $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$, i.e, $F_{t} = \sigma(X_s, 0 \leq s \leq t)$. Then it is well-known that $v$ solves the equation
$$ v(x) = \max \{ x, -d + E[v(X)] \},\quad  \forall x \in [0,N], \quad X \sim Unif[0,N]. $$
This can be solved easily: set $c = -d +E[v(X)]$ then $v(x) = x \vee c$ and so $E[v(X)] = \frac{N}{2} + \frac{c^2}{2N}$ and this yields
$$ x \vee c = x \vee \Big(-d + \frac{N}{2} + \frac{c^2}{2N}\Big) $$
or we must have $ \frac{c^2}{2N}-c -d + \frac{N}{2} = 0$ or $c = N - \sqrt{2Nd}$. For $N=50$, $d=4$ you get $c= 30$ as you were told.
Also, an optimal strategy (or optimal stopping time) is given by
$$ \tau^* = \inf \{t \geq 0: v(X_t) = X_t \} = \inf \{n \geq 0: X_t \geq  N - \sqrt{2Nd}\}, $$
that is, you stop after the first time you get a value greater than $ N - \sqrt{2Nd} $. For example, if $ d\geq N/2$, you stop immediately after the first draw.
